# How to prove this inclusion

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let $x\in\mathbb{Z}$ and $y\in\mathbb{Z}\setminus\{0\}$ and put $N_{x,y}=x\mathbb{Z}+y$.
I am just taking a self-help course on basic set theory and I want to prove that
$$\mathbb{Z}\setminus \bigcup_{k=1}^{x-1}N_{x,y+k}\subset N_{x,y}.$$
Can some help me?

Comment: You are right, I just fixed the typo.

Answer (score 1):

HINT: I’m going to assume that the $a$ in the subscript of the displayed formula is an error for $x$. The natural approach is to assume that

$$n\in\Bbb Z\setminus\bigcup_{k=1}^{x-1}N_{x,y+k}$$

and try to show that $n\in N_{x,y}$.

Suppose that $1\le k\le x-1$. We know that $n\notin N_{x,y+k}$, which means that $n-(y+k)$ is not a multiple of $x$. Thus, none of the $x-1$ consecutive integers

$$n-y-1,n-y-2,\dots,n-y-(x-1)$$

is a multiple of $x$. But every set of $x$ consecutive integers contains ... what?

Comment: I think you mixed up the "multiple of $a$" with "multiple of $x$" ;D

Comment: @Dan: Thought I’d caught all of those; thanks!

Comment: @Brian M. Scott ... it contains $y$?

Comment: @mary: No: $\{7,8,9\}$ is a set of three consecutive integers that doesn’t contain $3$. But it *does* contain a *multiple* of $3$.